# Regression with weights: Less standardized residuals then observations

Tags: r, linear-regression

I modelled a multiple Regression based on the Mincer-Wage-Equation and I added a weighting-factor to make it representative for the whole population.
But when I'm adding the weights function into my modell, R calculates less standardized residuals than I have observations.

Here's my modell:

```
lm(log(earings) ~ Gender + Age + Age^2 + Education, weights= phrf)
```

So I got problems to analyze the residuals because when I'm trying to plot the rstandard against the fitted.values R is telling: Different Variable Length in rstandard() found.

This Problem ist only by rstandard and rstudent, when I'm plotting the normal resid() against fitted.values there is no problem.

And when I'm leaving out the weights function I have not problems, too.

Comment: Could this perhaps be due to cases where `log(earings = 0) = -Inf`, which may result in some events being discarded? Otherwise, please post a minimal reproducible sample dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In the help file for `rstudent()`:

> Note that cases with weights == 0 are dropped from all these functions, but that if a linear model has been fitted with na.action = na.exclude, suitable values are filled in for the cases excluded during fitting.

A simple example to demonstrate:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- 1:100
y <- x + rnorm(100)
w <- runif(100)
w[44] <- 0

fit <- lm(y ~ x, weights=w)
length(fitted(fit))
length(rstudent(fit))
```

Gives:

```
> length(fitted(fit))
[1] 100
> length(rstudent(fit))
[1] 99
```

And this makes sense. If you have a weight of 0, the theoretical variance is 0 which is an infinite studentized or standardized residual.

Since you are effectively deleting those observations, you can subset the call to `lm` with `subset=w!=0` or you can use that flag for the fitted values:

`plot(fitted(fit)[w!=0], rstudent(fit))`